# Can't connect to postgresql with java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

In this simple example I can't connect to postgresql table. And I have no idea what's wrong. Please help.

```
package postgresql.jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;



public class PostgresWithJDBCConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // establishes database connection
        try (Connection connection =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/students", "postgres", "postgres")) {
            System.out.println("Connection established successfully");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Console returns

> "No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/students"

Comment: Did you download a JDBC driver for Postgres? If so, which one, and which version? Where did you put the driver’s JAR? What is your deployment scenario? Desktop app? Web app? If web app, what web container? Are you running from an IDE? Voting to close for lack of debugging details.

Comment: Please show how you are running your program. The error indicates that the PostgreSQL JDBC driver is not on the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downlaod the postgresql jdbc (https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) ad add it to your classpath